# Jest running all files in import Tree

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I've recently come across an interesting/peculiar side effect, wanted to know opinion of the experienced members out here.

When i run the command `npm run test -- --testPathPattern="filePath" --coverage`, I get the coverage info as follows -

```
    Statements   : 37.85% ( 5810/15350 )
    Branches     : 7.2% ( 547/7596 )
    Functions    : 10.66% ( 309/2898 )
    Lines        : 42.1% ( 5751/13660 )
    ================================================================================
```

5810 lines being run, 547 branches being tested is huge. I went debugging into this, and realized to an extent why this is happening.

All files in the import tree are are being run !!!

This could  potentially why CI takes time, and testing gets heavy.

Can i get any pointers on fixing this please

Answer (score 0):

It's not "all files in the import tree", it's all files period. The `--coverage` options collects the coverage stats of your codebase with tests, also generates a coverage report, that you probably don't need.

If this is a concern in the CI pipeline don't use the coverage option, just run the tests.

Comment: `npm run test <test file name> --coverage` isn't this supposed to run only that particular test ?

Comment: Yes, but it **ALSO** collects test coverage stats of the entire codebase. Drop the `--coverage` option if you don't need it (and if you want to run just 1 test you definitely don't need it) or configure where to collect coverage from by using this option: https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--collectcoveragefromglob